# Mac is boot looping after Mojave update. Can access disk utility. No backup. Can I get the data off it?

Tags: macbook-pro

Mac's are sorta new to me.

I have a friend's MacBook who recently updated to Mojave. It failed and now the Mac won't boot up. Just looping.

She doesn't have a backup of her data

I can assess the disk utility in the recovery mode. Can I use the to pull the data off the drive into another one safety? Then restore an OS and out the data back on?

It's a MacBook Pro around 2015 or earlier was running Yosemite. There's some important files on the Mac I'm hoping to get out.

Comment: From which macOS did you/your friend upgrade from?  Did it complete the process?  Which MacBook specifically (Pro, Air, etc.; include year)?  You can get into Recovery, launch Terminal and navigate to the `/Users` directory (`cd /Users`).  If the username for your friend is there, navigate into it and see if there is data (i.e. `Documents`, `Downloads`, etc.)

Comment: From Yosemite (before High Sierra?) I'm not sure if the installation went through 100%. I wasn't there. It's a MacBook Pro. Not sure of the year. Maybe 2015ish

Comment: The reason I ask is because High Sierra and up will convert the drive from HFS+ to APFS and it's possible that data corruption could happen.  However, you still need to go into Terminal and check the directories.  Also, be sure to [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/340824/edit) your question with the relevant details.

Comment: Ok so I typed in cd /Users and it comes up "no such file"

Comment: I think I was not accessing the main HDD I was accessing the disk image "OS X Base System" I'll check again.

Comment: Issue the command, diskutil list and post the results

Comment: I found this drive and have access to the users folders. Currently copying via terminal to another drive. I'll see how that goes...

Answer (score 1):

Reset the SMC (hold opt control shift and the power button for 20 seconds) then reset the NVRAM 3 times (3 on and off of the lcd monitors backlight) first.

Try to boot into Recovery mode or Internet Recovery (option command and R keys).

Is it looping after the Apple logo has come on the screen? If so then you probably can do what you mention since in that case it's likely a software issue although the drive could be failing. Do you mean the update failed and then the OS wouldn't boot right after?

Comment: I can get to the login screen when I log in it glitches out (black text error appears on the screen and reboots)

Comment: What does resetting the controller that handles power regulation and what in the NVRAM settings would be related to a boot loop?

Answer (score 1):

If it were me I would try to boot the other Mac in target disk mode.

This will mount the target machines HD  as an external drive connected to the host so you can, for example, copy all the files to another hard drive.

More info here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201462

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'd love to but it seems like I don't have a compatible Mac to use as the host